# a question about Taylor's theorem

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I know if I have $a < b$ and If a function  an it's  derivatives satisfy the conditions  of Taylor's theorem  then $f (b)=f (a)+f'(a)(b-a)+ \frac {f''(a)}{2}(b-a)^2$ $+......+$ $\frac {f{(a)}^n {(b-a)}^n}{(n!)}$. 
can I write the same formula to express $f (b)$ in terms of $f (a)$ if $b <a$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Yes, as long as the function can be described by a power series (i.e. it is analytic). the formula works for $b$ sufficiently close to $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have written Taylor's formula it is only valid for arbitrary $a$ and $b$ if $f$is a polynomial of degree $\leq n$. In all other cases there is an error term $R_n$, which can be presented in various forms, all of them exhibiting that $|R_n|$ is **very** small if $n\gg1$  and $|b-a|\ll1$.

One more thing: Yes, $b$ may be $<a$ as well.